# How to open copied file by VI

Tags: bash

Say, I have 'a.txt'. I would like to copy the file and open the newly copied file using VI.

```
cp a.txt b.txt
vi b.txt
```

How to combine the two command in a command?

Comment: Hmm I’ve got to ask: *why*?!

Comment: @Rudolph Because of the curiosity and laziness. In addition, I think someday, I can apply the method to the other problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use vi itself to do the copy, by opening a.txt then saving the contents to b.txt (effectively copying it) and then switching to b.txt.

Putting it all together:

```
vi -c 'w b.txt' -c 'e#' a.txt
```

This is equivalent to running `vi a.txt`, followed by the `:w b.txt` command (inside `vi`), which will save the contents to a file named b.txt. But vi will still be editing a.txt at this point, so you follow up with the `:e#` command, which means "edit alternative file" (or "edit last file") and given vi has just touched b.txt, it will switch to editing that file.

Comment: Im not sure if vi has `saveas` (it may have come from vim) but it would shorten the command.

Comment: The `:f` command may be useful - that will just change the filename, and the user can write it the normal way at the end of the editing session with `:wq`.

Answer (score 4):

using `&&` operator

```
cp a.txt b.txt && vi b.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way where I can type b.txt only once?

Comment: @comphys `src=a.txt; dst=b.txt; cp "$src" "$dst" && vi "$dst"`

Comment: @comphys Yes we actually can: `cp a.txt b.txt && vi $_`. Grump reminded me of this in another comment thread.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own function and use that function.
In the below example, you can use cp1 as a command.

**example:**

```
$ cat test.txt
function cp1() {
  source_file=$1
  destination_file=$2
  cp "${source_file}" "${destination_file}"
  vi "${destination}"
}

$ . ./test.txt    
$ cp1 a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: I would like to know an ad hoc method which can be written in one command line. Anyway, thank you for the helpful answer.

Comment: @comphys If this is something you do frequently, why not define a function for it? If you don't do it enough to need a function, why does it even matter?

Comment: @Barmar I don't frequently encounter this kind of situation. However, I wanted to know the answer to apply it to the other similar situation and the curiosity makes me ask!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a way to save you typing you can use bash build in functionality to repeat the last word of the previous command. You can do this by <kbd>ALT+.</kbd>

```
> cp a.txt b.txt
> vi ALT+.
```

Very useful, and reminds you of the dot operator of vim.

Happy golfing.

Comment: Hmm this doesn’t seem to work for me. Is this a readline Emacs command (I’m working in vim mode)?

Comment: !$ may be better than ALT+.

Comment: @Grump That's indeed an interesting suggestion. I haven't thought of using that stuff. Actually $_ is more interesting, because it repeats the last executed command as opposed to the last command in history (that is what !$ does). But why would it be better. If we count keystrokes it is more and I also think the special symbols are a bit hard to reach.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Indeed, this is for the emacs readline mode. Vim mode has the same functionality, but since . already has a function underscore is used here. ALT + Underscore also works in emacs mode btw.

Comment: !$ is the last *argument* from the last  command in history. I suggest it because it works in more shells and doesn't rely on keybindings

Comment: Agree with Grump, but @KonradRudolph try hitting escape (not holding it) and then `.`.

Comment: @Kevin This is indeed a trick that works if your alt key does not work in emacs mode. The reason for this is that most terminal emulators treat key after escape and alt plus key the same. So if your alt key does not work, you can trick the terminal emulator with a key after escape. But if you are in vi mode this most likely will not work. On my machine I could however force it to work with `'"\e.":yank-last-arg'`, but somehow this binding then only worked when in normal mode, and not when in insert mode.